# Why search field do an "OR" search, not an "AND" search

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm wondering why search bar do an "OR" search, not an "AND" search. Someone says that a part of specification and others say that is miss-configuration. Which is correct?

Askbot itself is able to perform AND search (see https://ask.fedoraproject.org/questions/).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/88181/why-search-field-do-an-%22or%22-search,-not-an-%22and%22-search/) by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1186 on 2013-10-07

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-10-07**:
I know this doesn't help with the actual problem, but I actually get better results by just using google (maybe adding a site:answers.ros.org).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure if there is a good answer to the "why?" question. I know the change from OR to AND is ticketed on the [ROS Answers issue tracker](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/answers.ros.org/issues/27) though. It´s been 9 months since that ticket got created, so maybe an encouraging post there will get things moving :)

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2013-10-07**:
Thanks, I left comment there. if someone find how to fix this, please add comment.